# Centering elements in column with neat

Tags: html, sass, neat

I'm just getting started with neat and I'm working on the admin page for a site. I'm just trying to recreate a pretty standard page where the settings show up in the center of the screen, and I'm just curious how you do this with neat.

In the past I probably would have done this by setting `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto` on most of the elements I wanted centered.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<!-- admin.html -->

...
<div class="settings">
  <div id="instagramLogin">
    <h3>Instagram</h3>
      <a href="https://instagram.com/.....">Sign in with Instagram</a>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

```scss
//admin.scss
.settings{
  @include span-columns(4);
  @include shift(4);
}

#instagramLogin{
  @include shift(2);
}
```

It looks right visually, but it just seems like the wrong thing to be doing.

Comment: You do understand that Sass/Neat just compiles to CSS, right?  There are literally only a couple ways to center an element in CSS.

Comment: Yes I obviously understand that sass compiles to CSS. I thought that there might be a way to do this using the mixins that neat provides. If there isn't, you can just say that